# Subset dataframe with sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I try to subset dataframe using sqlfd but it doesn't work. Can someone explain why? I have processed like this.

```
library(sqldf)
dataf <- read.csv("zert.csv")
```

`agep` & `pwgt1` are columns of dataf

```
dd <- sqldf("select * from dataf where AGEP < 50 and pwgtp1")
```

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :
>
> Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user
>   'rodrigue'@'localhost' (using password: NO) Error in !dbPreExists :
>   invalid argument type

Comment: Try it in a fresh session.  Make sure you don't have any library statements in your `.Rprofile` .  Try adding `verbose = TRUE` as an argument to `sqldf`.  When posting to SO all inputs should be included so that it is reproducible by anyone else.

Comment: In addition to @G.Grothendieck: [Info on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: THANK @G.Grothendieck and . despite your tips i don't find anything. when i try in the fresh session and add 'verbose = TRUE' as an argument to sqldf i have  '> dd  <- sqlfd("select * from dataf where AGEP < 50 and pwgtp1", verbose = TRUE)' '>sqldf: library(RMySQL)'
'>sqldf: m <- dbDriver("MySQL")'
'Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'rodrigue'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type'

Comment: Yes, it did show somethinig. It showed that you have issued a library(MySQL) call which you did not show us.  Was it your intention to use MySQL?  Remove the call to library(MySQL) and just use it with SQLite or else read the documentation and set up MySQL to work with sqldf.

Answer (score 0):

sqldf need a SQL Provider and in your comment it seems you have **MYSQL** and it needs password to connect.
therefor you need `password` *option* in `sqldf` function.
any way
let me give you a suggestion: forget SQL and believe R has itself syntax that more power full of SQL.
R has more power full and fast package `data.table`.
this is your answer more fast of any other way:

```
require(data.table)
Dt=fread('/path/to/File.csv',there are some useful options)
setkey(Dt,AGEP) # if it is huge file
ddf=Dt[AGEP<50 & pwgtp1,]
```

Comment: thank for your tip it walk very well but, i need to use sqldf function for this task

Comment: When using MySQL, sqldf does not use the password argument or option. To set up MySQL to work with sqldf read `?sqldf`.